# Security concerns while pushing to public dockerhub repository via command line

Tags: docker, security, daemon, dockerhub, docker-desktop

I am trying to push a docker image to a repository and having several problems. I have my local development environment set up with Docker desktop on OSX. Now, I need to to push the updated image to dockerhub, so it can be pulled into Kubernetes. I can't be sure, but I think I received security warnings from my workplace after trying that action.

Are there known security risks with connecting to dockerhub?

Do I need to protect the daemon socket? Our desktop guy send this to me, but I am not connecting to a host other than Dockerhub, so is the following still relevant? https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/protect-access/

Comment: Please post the security warnings you get when connecting to dockerhub. It would be important to know what we are dealing with exactly.

Comment: And I don't see how the protection of docker deamon socket could be related to what you are facing.

Comment: It was a TLS vulnerability.

Comment: We will not move forward without knowing the security warning content. We need more info.